# Is there an unhandled exception handler in Java?

Tags: java, exception

If i remember correctly in .NET one can register "global" handlers for unhandled exceptions. I am wondering if there is something similar for Java.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there's the [`defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28%29), but it only triggers if the `Thread` doesn't have a [`uncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getUncaughtExceptionHandler%28%29) set.

Answer (score 5):

Yes

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an 'almost' global such handler available in [ThreadGroup](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable)). It is not as global as the one you are mentioning, but you can basically achieve the same functionality.

Starting with Java 5, there is a similar functionality available directly on the [Thread class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

Often, Java frameworks like Struts and Spring (and the Servlet Spec, IIRC) allow you to set a global exception handler.  These mechanisms are specific to each framework, though.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Unhandled exception in Java:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t1, Throwable e1) {
   // Exception handling code  
  }
});
```

Stole it from [here](https://rollbar.com/guides/java-exception-handling/)

Answer (score -4):

Assuming it is like catch(...) in C++ you would do:

```
try
{
   // your code here
}
catch(Throwable ex)
{
   // any sort of exception, even if the VM has choked on a peanut
}
```

In general this isn't a good idea unless you are dealing with 3rd party code (you should try to always throw subclasses of Exception (and not RuntimeException) in your own code - unless it indicates a programmer error that should be delt with via unit testing.