# who handles RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception

I have a class extends HttpServlet contains following two methods. When a client makes a request to web app running on a Tomcat server, http request will be handled via this class however if doSomething method throws RunTimeException how it gets handled based on below example?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest reqst, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        doSomething();
}

private void doSomething() {
     if (false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("exception caught calling doSomething method");
     }
     else {
        ...
     }
}
```

[update]
Can I add try/catch block inside of doPost where doSomething() is invoked?

Comment: Yes, you can always add `try`/`catch`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an unhandled exception handler in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588634/is-there-an-unhandled-exception-handler-in-java)

Comment: Obviously, you can have `try catch` and handle exceptions in your code. If you don't handle, it propagates and who handles it depends on the particular servlet specification implementation.

Comment: You can always connect a debugger, set a breakpoint, and `throw new RuntimeException()` to see where it goes.  Just keep in mind that the execution path you discover by this method also depends on your servlet container implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All exceptions that reach servlet container code (i.e., those thrown or re-thrown by the `doPost()` method) will get handled such that Tomcat generates a 500 response, sets `Content-Type` to `text/html`, and generates a full HTML page in the body which says that an internal server error has occured, attaching the name and stack trace of the exception.

RE: your [Update]: yes, you can add a try-catch there. In fact, any reasonable implementation *will* include it. You want your application to dictate what response is sent to your client, not Tomcat or any other container.

Comment: understood. I learned something new today. have a blessed day!