# Make Exceptions do things by default

Tags: java, exception

I'm making a game in java where I use quite a few "delicate tools" like filewriters, Gl, Al, ect. In my exit method in my game I close all that has to be closed, but if something unpredicted happens and if an exception is thrown I get warnings in the console about these unclosed things, which I have a hunch might not be too good.

I know I can configure all my trys', catch and finally blocks, but that would be a pain and make my code ugly, so I wonder if there another way. Basically I want to tell the JVM that "when an exception is thrown, don't do System.exit() do THIS first....

THIS = close this, close that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588634/is-there-an-unhandled-exception-handler-in-java may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is best that you use [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) for the things that need to get closed. An AutoCloseable object will take care to call its close method. This would make the code cleaner and easier to debug.

Also have a look at [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: I fully agree, this is the optimal strategy and it's worth rewriting code to use try-with-resources. But if/when that isn't possible, there's [`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))

Comment: Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler was what I was looking for.

Comment: @biziclop please consider posting this as an answer. Apparently your comment resolved the issue and thus I believe it should be an answer and should be the accepted answer.