# Not getting Guice injection issues via SLF4J to file

Tags: java, guice, slf4j

Am I doing something wrong, or is this really expected behavior?  Let me explain:

When trying to run a Java program with Guice DI, if there is something wrong with my classpath (or any other binding issue) I expect to get an exception that looks something like this:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
>
> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class `<any class here>`

This actually lets me know I have a classpath issue, and is one of the things I love about Guice (telling you exactly what's wrong).

When I run this program via the command line using SLF4J (specifically logback implementation), I am able to get that error, but only in console output.  If I run this in a way that diverts all console output to /dev/null (for instance), the exception never makes it into the file so I can't tell it's happening.  I can log as much as I want before the error, so it's not a problem of a bad configuration in that respect.  I even tried adding the jcl-over-slf4j and log4j-over-slf4j jars to the classpath to try to pick up something to no avail.

Maybe I'm not using the right keywords but I'm not able to find anybody else reporting the same issue, so I can't tell if this is a problem in my configuration or a "feature" of Guice.

So basicaly, is this a configuration issue or a "feature"/bug in Guice where I am not able to see the binding exceptions in my log file?

For any still interested here is my logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>debug.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC_CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't a log warning, it's an exception on the main thread, and Java is dutifully logging it to standard error before terminating your program. I don't believe SLF4J redirects stderr, or changes the default exception handler; you'd get the same behavior (skipping SLF4J and going to standard error) for any exception including `throw new RuntimeException()`.

In terms of fixes, that depends on how deeply you want to adjust your setup:

- If there are certain object creations that are likely to fail, and you want the app to continue running, you'd probably want to catch `CreationException` in a `try`/`catch` block. Then you can pass the logging message to SLF4J and recover gracefully.
- If this is a program where you don't want or expect the console for any input or output, you can reset stdin, stdout, and stderr through [`System` calls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr(java.io.PrintStream)), but that could be seen as confusing and somewhat drastic.
- As in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588634/1426891), you can make a change to the default exception handler of your main thread, so that failures go to SLF4J instead of stderr. You would probably still be unable to recover, though: by the time you catch an exception in the thread, there's nowhere else to resume execution.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do a quick test of grabbing some code from the SO question you mentioned and that does allow me to get the errors to the file.  My biggest problem with the file not showing up in a log file is that the program doesn't actually terminate because some classes that create threads.  Because I do not have any console output, I have no way to diagnose why something is not working as expected (until I redirect standard error).

Answer (score 1):

I have read that Guice uses the Java logger for its implementation.  I believe what you are seeing is Guice using one logger (that is logging to the console) and then the SLF4J being configured with your desired logging config.  Have you set Guice to use the SLF4J for its logger implementation?

Comment: With that thought, I added the jul-to-slf4j.jar to my classpath as per [slf4j documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) and also followed the programmatic installation steps in [more slf4j documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html).  Unfortunately this didn't help.  I am going to try to create an easily runnable example of this problem.